# How to access a json field with "~" in the field name with Presto JSON functions

Tags: json, presto, trino

I have a "~" in my json fields, such as "~id". Using Presto 0.75, I am unable to access such fields. Following is what I have tried so far without success:

SELECT json_extract_scalar('{"id":"1","table":"test"}', '$.table'); // This works

SELECT json_extract_scalar('{"id":"1","~table":"test"}', '$.[\"~table\"]'); // Doesn't work

SELECT json_extract_scalar('{"id":"1","~table":"test"}', '$.[\~table]'); // Doesn't work

Error given is "Invalid JSON path:"

Comment: are you try  `'$[~table]'` or `'$["~table"]'`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The correct form for that JSON path is: `'$["~table"]'`:

```
presto> SELECT json_extract_scalar('{"id":"1","~table":"test"}', '$["~table"]');

 _col0 
-------
 test  
(1 row)
```

Here are some facts to help you understand why the alternatives you tried don't work:

- The JSON path expression is represented with a SQL string. The only character that needs escaping is the string delimiter (i.e., single quote), and the way you to do it is with another single quote. For example: `'don''t'` is the SQL string literal for `don't`. Double quotes within a SQL string literal do not need to be escaped.
- JSON path expressions support two forms for accessing attributes: field vs array element access. If you have an attribute named "foo", you can access it either with `'$["foo"]'` or `'$.foo'`. The field access syntax only works for names that are valid identifiers (alphanumeric and underscores).

Comment: same concept applies for "-" hyphen or dash character as well. i was facing similar issue in AWS Athena which relies on presto json functions.

Comment: Just in case you're wondering, the array element like this to access nested elements such as `{"foo":{"~bar":1}}` 'would look like this: `$["foo"]["~bar"]`